# clock_gettime returning weird results

Tags: c, timing

I am trying to time different algorithms in C to determine which ones are faster. For example, consider the following (naive) function to find the sum of the even fibonacci numbers less than a certain other number:

```
static long a(long under) {
  long x = 0, y = 1;
  long sum = 0;
  do {
    if (!(x % 2))
      sum += x;
    const long tmp = x;
    x += y;
    y = tmp;
  } while (x < under);
  return sum;
}
```

This function seems to me like it should run in logarithmic time with respect to the input (the number of loop iterations should be something like log_phi(under)).

However, when I time this function, it takes less time the higher the input is. Here is a full reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static long a(long under) {
  long x = 0, y = 1;
  long sum = 0;
  do {
    if (!(x % 2))
      sum += x;
    const long tmp = x;
    x += y;
    y = tmp;
  } while (x < under);
  return sum;
}

static long time_a(long value) {
  struct timespec start, end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
  a(value);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
  return end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec + (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000;
}

void main() {
  const long t1 = time_a(1000);
  const long t2 = time_a(1000000);
  const long t3 = time_a(1000000000);

  printf("time for       1000: %ld ns\n", t1);
  printf("time for    1000000: %ld ns\n", t2);
  printf("time for 1000000000: %ld ns\n", t3);
}
```

If I compile this with GCC and then run it, I get the following output:

```
time for       1000: 4483 ns
time for    1000000: 2564 ns
time for 1000000000: 2514 ns
```

What is going on here?

Edit: I am using GCC 11.2.1 with glibc 2.34, on Gentoo Linux with kernel 5.15.11. The code was compiled with `gcc test.c -o test`. Looking at the binary in objdump, GCC is not optimizing out the call to `a` when compiled this way. The code is being run on an HP ZBook 15u G4 with an Intel i5-7200U.

Comment: When asking questions like this in the future, include the version of GCC you used, the switches you used to compile, and information about the system you executed it on, including the processor model. For this code, calculating the Fibonacci numbers does not take much time; most of the time in the last two measurements is actually spent in the call to `clock_gettime`. In the first measurement, not everything is in cache, so time is consumed getting things into cache.

Comment: And, if you compile with clang, the loops are removed entirely. The statement `a(value);` has no *observable behavior*, so the optimizer can remove it from the program entirely, and then the program only reports the time between two successive calls to `clock_gettime` with minimal instructions between them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have edited the question to have information about the environment. If I were to call the function once before timing it, would that fix the irregularities from the caching? Also, is there some way when compiling with optimizations to tell the compiler not to optimize out a particular function call whose return value is discarded?

Comment: Re “If I were to call the function once before timing it, would that fix the irregularities from the caching?”: Mostly. It can be tricky.

Comment: Re “Also, is there some way when compiling with optimizations to tell the compiler not to optimize out a particular function call whose return value is discarded?”: You can declare a variable `volatile` and store the result into it. Accesses to volatile objects are *observable behavior* by definition; the compiler must actually implement them. It could still determine the result is computable at compile time and eliminate the computation. You can make the input to the function volatile, which prevents the compiler from knowing what it is in advance.

Comment: Try reversing the sequence check if it is still taking more time for `time_a(1000)` as compare to time taken for `time_a(1000000000)` and `time_a(1000000)`. Also, note that this `end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec` can result in negative number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it loops I think https://godbolt.org/z/x8ooaY1sG, even now https://godbolt.org/z/81b4ef6GW but the effect is the same

Comment: @EricPostpischil I modified the main function to call time_a once and discard the value before timing the different arguments. To try to minimize the effect of clock_gettime taking some time, (prepare yourself, this is ugly), I changed it to call a 1000 times in a for loop between the clock_gettimes, and then divide the difference by 1000. Now, I am getting values much more in line with what I expected: 1000 - 57ns, 1000000 - 104ns, 1000000000 - 149ns, and 1000000000000 - 218ns. Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The condition on line 8: `if (!(x % 2))` is evaluated 17 times, 48 times and 93 times for the inputs `1000`, `1000000` and `1000000000`.

These are simply *too few* iterations -- your measurement overhead is larger than the time you are trying to measure.

To measure this reliably, invoke `a()` 1,000,000 times and measure the total time taken.

When I do that, and divide the time by `1e6`, I get:

```
time for       1000:    49.81 ns
time for    1000000:    59.16 ns
time for 1000000000:    85.02 ns
```

which at least goes in the right direction.

P.S. Measuring performance of unoptimized code is a fool's errand: the compiler may introduce all kinds of artifacts.